# Xamarin.Forms - Slider not updating on property assignment in iOS, works in Android

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I have a particular screen in my Xamarin.Forms project. In the XAML file I create a `Slider` element, and in the code behind I access the slider to update its value, but the UI never changes on iOS. Works perfectly on Android. Here's the relevant code:

**XAML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="TnpApp.Forms.AudioPlayer" BackgroundColor="Gray">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Padding="16" >
            // ...
            <Slider x:Name="ProgressSlider" Minimum="0" Maximum="100"/>
            // ...
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

**Code behind** (a method that gets called at a specified interval to update the UI)

```
void UpdateCTI(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    var progress = DependencyService.Get<IAudioPlayer>().GetAudioProgress();
    ProgressSlider.Value = progress;
}
```

I've confirmed that this method gets called every second as it's supposed to, and the value in the progress variable is correct. The value returned from `ProgressSlider.Value` (determined with `Console.WriteLine()`) updates to 1 when `progress` updates to 1, but doesn't change after that even though `progress` continues growing as expected.

Again, this issue is only on iOS, everything works perfectly on Android.

Can anyone help me out here?

Comment: If UpdateCTI is being executed by a threaded timer then that function is being executed in a secondary thread, use Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread

Comment: @Gusman Thanks, that fixes it! Post this as an answer and I'll accept it. Strange that it still worked on Android...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your code is being executed on a threaded timer then the code is being executed on a secondary thread and it can't acces the UI.

To run the code on the primary thread use Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread:

```
void UpdateCTI(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
     var progress = DependencyService.Get<IAudioPlayer>().GetAudioProgress();
     Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread (() => ProgressSlider.Value = progress);
}
```

Comment: Here's the link that details this: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/platform-features/device/#Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread